# Monogame Unit Test Color

Tags: c#, unit-testing, monogame

I have a unit test in my MonoGame project, that checks if de color is equals another color:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void PeronagemColorTest()
    {
        var color = new Color(255,255,255,255);

        var color2 = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);

        if (!color.Equals(color2))
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
```

But the color cannot be compared, and give me a message:

> error CS0103: The name 'DebugDisplayString' does not exist in the current context

What is really happens?

Comment: Is `DebugDisplayString` related to the color comparison? Because I don't see that value back in the given code.

Comment: @Steven I think it has something to do with this https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/989dbe64ab1f629e92af25427c4b25c3895fe130/MonoGame.Framework/Color.cs#L16

Comment: Looks like a compile time error